# Select multiple child columns with the same filter

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Linq lambda expression which generates abnormally complex SQL select to database. Is it somehow possibility to simplify it?

```
var devices = db.Devices
                        .Where(a => a.active == true)
                        .Select(a => new DeviceToDisplay
                        {
                            Id = a.Id,
                            serialNumber = a.serialNumber,                               
                            deviceRegion = a.deviceRegion,
                            activeIP = a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active == true).Select(b => b.IPaddress1).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Wip = a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active == true).Select(b => b.W_IP).FirstOrDefault(),
                            Sip = a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active == true).Select(b => b.S_IP).FirstOrDefault(),
                            model = a.SPdatas.Where(c => c.model != "").OrderByDescending(c => c.collectionDate).Select(c => c.model).FirstOrDefault(),
                            firmware = a.SPdatas.Where(c => c.model != "").OrderByDescending(c => c.collectionDate).Select(c => c.firmware).FirstOrDefault(),                               
                            lastMPteamActivity = a.activityLogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.updatedDate).Select(c => c.updatedDate).FirstOrDefault(),                               
                            country = a.MPPinformations.Select(c => c.country).FirstOrDefault()                                
                        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, your linq query looks very complicated. Imagine how you would implement this by writing a SQL query for example.

A suggestion: you are writing things like:

```
 a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active == true).
```

and

```
  a.SPdatas.Where(c => c.model != "").OrderByDescending(c => c.collectionDate).
```

in multiple places.

Instead you could create an anonymous type. For example,

```
var foo = from x in sb.Devices.Where(a=> a.active)
          select new { Id = x.ID, 
                       IPAddress = a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active), ... }
```

You can then use `foo` to create your Devices object.

Comment: This decreased my page load time from 5 seconds to 0.5 seconds... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

See if this is any better:

```
var devices = db.Devices
  .Where(a => a.active == true)
  .Select(a => new DeviceToDisplay {
    Id = a.Id,
    serialNumber = a.serialNumber,                               
    deviceRegion = a.deviceRegion,
    activeIP = a.IPaddresses.Where(b => b.active == true).FirstOrDefault(),
    SPdata = a.SPdatas.Where(c => c.model != "").OrderByDescending(c => c.collectionDate).FirstOrDefault(),
    lastMPteamActivity = a.activityLogs.OrderByDescending(c => c.updatedDate).Select(c => c.updatedDate).FirstOrDefault(),                               
    country = a.MPPinformations.Select(c => c.country).FirstOrDefault()                                
})
  .Select(a=> new DeviceToDisplay {
    Id=a.Id,
    serialNumber=a.serialNumber,
    deviceRegion=a.deviceRegion,
    activeIP=a.activeIP.IPaddress1,
    Wip=a.activeIP.W_IP,
    Sip=a.activeIP.S_IP,
    model=a.SPdata.model,
    firmware=a.SPdata.firmware,
    lastMPteamActivity=a.lastMPteamActivity,
    country=a.county
});
```

Comment: This is similar approach as Leigh below suggested and it decreased my page load time from 5 seconds to 0.5 seconds... Thank you!